# Does nextjs automatically sanitize post requests and request parameters?

Tags: security, next.js

Can I assume that api requests using nextjs are automatically sanitized and limited, or is security not included with nextjs?

```
export default async function handler(req, res) { }
```

Is everything such as req.body and req.query safe and escaped by default? Or will I need to manually sanitize the request

Comment: What threats are you trying to mitigate in req.body or req.query specifically?

Answer (score 2):

String identifiers like **"** and **'** (`"` or `%27` URL encoded) will be escaped with a backslash, resulting in **\'** or **\"**.

For SQL queries with parameters wrapped in string identifiers like `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = '${request.query.id}'"` this is enough to prevent an SQL injection.